How to Delete All Files from a Directory Daily Using Cron?
I need to delete all files from a specific folder every day using a cron job. My current crontab entry looks like this:
0 22 * * * rm -rf /var/www/abcd/app/Management/application/session/*

However, this does not always work, especially when there are a large number of files in the folder. Sometimes I get the error, as i redirect the error into file using this crontab:
0 22 * * * rm -rf /var/www/abcd/app/Management/application/session/* >> /home/ubuntu/errorgetter.log 2>&1

This is the error:
/bin/sh: 1: /bin/rm: Argument list too long

Note: I created crontab -e as root user, so there is no permission issue to delete it.
Now How will i do this?

This question is similar to: Argument list too long when removing files in trash. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I was able to solve this issue using the find command in my cron job. Here’s the updated crontab entry that worked for me:
0 22 * * * find /var/www/abcd/app/Management/application/session/ -type f -delete

Why This Works:

find: Processes files individually, avoiding the "Argument list too long" error that occurs when using rm with too many files.
-type f: Ensures only files are deleted (not directories).
-delete: Deletes each file directly without expanding into a long argument list.

So Now this will run automatically every day at 10 PM to remove all files from the specified folder.
Note:
Ensure that the user running the cron job has the necessary permissions to delete files in the specified directory. You can verify this by manually running the command as the same user. If permission issues occur, you might need to adjust ownership or file permissions using chmod or chown.
If you run crontab -e as the root user, the cron job will be executed by the root user.
If you run crontab -e as a regular user (for example, a user like ubuntu or www-data) the cron job will be executed by that particular user.
To View cronjob of specific user: sudo crontab -u <username> -l

You may want to replace the -type f argument with -mindepth 1. This will delete ALL of the contents of the folder, without deleting the folder itself.
